# I am trying to make a small program that manages stock levels and would like to know how to start it in python

Tags: python

I would like to develop the program to be able to retrieve and display information from a text file so I would like to know how to point it.

I would like to retrieve the information by the user inputting a certain product code and the program searching through the text file for it. In addition, I would like the user to be able to input a certain quantity of a product and the program be able to calculate the total cost using the individual price from the text file. I need it to display the related information such as an item name and price. I would also like it to identify any products not found. The output should be almost like a receipt.

I do not have any code as of yet as I do not know where to start but iIhave made the text file including all of its data.

This is my text file:

```
GTIN: 34512340 plain brackets                 Quantity: 4        Individual Price:  0.50
GTIN: 98981236 product not found 
GTIN: 56756777 100 mm bolts                   Quantity: 32       Individual Price:  0.20
GTIN: 90673412 L-shaped brackets              Quantity: 6        Individual Price:  1.20
GTIN: 13245627 100 mm nuts                    Quantity: 32       Individual Peice:  0.20
```

Comment: This is not really a question that can be answered here and is likely to get down voted.  You need to ask short specific questions and read Python docs.  Think in small steps, 1. How do I read a file, 2. How do I create Classes to store object information, 3, How do I create class methods.  You also need an understanding of data types, lists, tuples, dictionaries etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use csv module, there are some rules your text file must provide like `,`(but ofcourse you dont have to use this it can be a space, colon(:) etc.) character beetwen columns :

```
import csv

with open('c.txt', 'r') as cfile:
    content = csv.reader(cfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in content:
        print(row)
```

---

```
# c.txt
GTIN, Quantity, Individual Price
34512340 plain brackets, 4, 0.50
34512340 product not found
56756777 100 mm bolts, 32, 0.20

# output
['GTIN', ' Quantity', ' Individual Price']
['34512340 plain brackets', ' 4', ' 0.50']
['34512340 product not found']
['56756777 100 mm bolts', ' 32', ' 0.20']
```

[python csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents)

Comment: I seem to be getting an error it is telling me that the file i point at does not have a valid file name followed by a line number?

Comment: are you sure your text file content like mine. show me error.

Comment: I attached an error image to your solution

Comment: it is about your formatting code. write those codes to a file then this code file and c.txt file both keep in same directory. `run>cmd` type `C:\Python27\python.exe codefile.py`